# how to check if zfs is using the kernel module

Tags: kernel, performance, zfs

I am having perfomance troubles (transfer rates only about 50MB/s using 6 2TB server hdds WDC WD2003FYYS, each doing app 150 MB/s) with my raidz and was hoping to increase it with the ZFS on Linux kernel module. The system runs Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a G630T CPU with 2x1GB RAM.
I installed the module using these commands:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable
apt-get install -y ubuntu-zfs
modprobe zfs
zpool import Media
```

How can I check if the module is now used for zfs acivities - after all it was running without the kernel module beforehand.

BTW: the performance still sucks :-|

```
bonnie++ -d /mnt/Media/ -u 1000
Version  1.97       ------Sequential Output------ --Sequential Input- --Random-
Concurrency   1     -Per Chr- --Block-- -Rewrite- -Per Chr- --Block-- --Seeks--
Machine        Size K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP  /sec %CP
Nero          3232M    85  99 86174  16 50680  12   263  99 261051  20 247.7   8
Latency               108ms    1172ms    5596ms   42597us     248ms     660ms
Version  1.97       ------Sequential Create------ --------Random Create--------
Nero                -Create-- --Read--- -Delete-- -Create-- --Read--- -Delete--
              files  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP
                 16 10521  52 +++++ +++ 20070  91 15216  90 +++++ +++ 18939  85
Latency               497ms     398us    9783us     118ms      32us     100us
1.97,1.97,Nero,1,1427965005,3232M,,85,99,86174,16,50680,12,263,99,261051,20,247.7,8,16,,,    ,,10521,52,+++++,+++,20070,91,15216,90,+++++,+++,18939,85,108ms,1172ms,5596ms,42597us,248    ms,660ms,497ms,398us,9783us,118ms,32us,100us
```

LSMOD:

```
lsmod |grep zfs
zfs                  1213833  1
zunicode              331251  1 zfs
zavl                   15010  1 zfs
zcommon                51321  1 zfs
znvpair                89166  2 zfs,zcommon
spl                   175426  5 zfs,zavl,zunicode,zcommon,znvpair
```

Comment: Output of `lsmod`

Comment: I added the lsmod output - the module is loaded but is it also used? after all i used zfs before without the module and did not change anything but compiling and loading the module.

Comment: I'm no expert for ZFS, but when installing FreeNAS with ZFS the manual said you need to hav approx. 1GB RAM for each 1TB of the ZFS or the performance will be cruel. see https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/zfs-memory-requirements.16874/ and https://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFSTuningGuide

Comment: Yes, the numbers list the number of modules using zfs and which ones are using it (zunicode is using zfs for example). See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-display-list-of-modules-or-device-drivers-in-the-linux-kernel/

Comment: Does that mean that the module is correctly used by the system?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the performance issue. It was quite simple: Got myself 2x2GB RAM, put it into the computer, voila. It now has 6GB of memory and seems to be happy about it.

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/Media/testfile.out bs=1M count=10000
>   10000+0 records in
>   10000+0 records out
>   10485760000 bytes (10 GB) copied, 33.828 s, 310 MB/s
>
> dd if=/mnt/Media/testfile.out of=/dev/null bs=1M
>   10000+0 records in
>   10000+0 records out
>   10485760000 bytes (10 GB) copied, 24.1512 s, 434 MB/s

I never tested if the zfs kernel module did any good.

Why was it so difficult to figure this out? The reason is that the memory never filled up completely when only 2 GB was installed. Also, there was no swapping going on - at least not during file operations. A hint that I better should have paid more attention to, was however to be found in "top" Whenever I was copying files the wait states (wa) raised to about 30 %. After the upgrade this value stays below 5 %.